# The .Save () method of the Edraw Office component does not work in my client server application

Tags: asp-classic

I have a problem and it is that if I have a URL like: `"Y: \ SAGRU \ storage \ resolutions \ DAC \ MGA \ 2021 \ 05 \ MGA-0003-2021.docx"` to load a document the `OA1.Save ()` method works correctly and the changes in the document are executed, but if the url is: `"http: \\ 192.168.3.130:81\almacen\resoluciones\DAC\MGA\2021\05\MGA-0003-2021.docx"` the OA1 method `.Save ()` does not work, changes to the document are not displayed.

To upload a document I have the following code:

```
dim url, ext, soloLectura, progID, webUsuario, webPwd
url = ""
<%
'### AVERIGUAR EL URL webDAV del ARCHIVO'
set conC = Application("conn").EXECUTE("SELECT * FROM Resoluciones WHERE idResolucion="&idres)
IF NOT conC.EOF THEN
    response.write VBNEWLINE
    dim tmpCarpetaRes, tmpArchivoRes, tmpRutaArch, tmpURLArch
    tmpCarpetaRes = conC("idDepartamentoINE")&"/"&conC("idSucursalINE")&"/"&conC("anoEmitida")&"/"&rellena(MONTH(conC("fechaEmitida")), 2)
    tmpArchivoRes = dameFormatoNumRes(conC("fechaEmitida"), conC("idDepartamentoINE"), conC("idSucursalINE"), conC("anoEmitida"), conC("numeroResolucion"))
    tmpRutaArch   = server.mappath("./almacen/resoluciones/"&tmpCarpetaRes&"/"&tmpArchivoRes&".doc")        
    tmpURLArch    = "http://"&request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME")&":"&request.servervariables("SERVER_PORT")&"/resoluciones/"&tmpCarpetaRes&"/"&tmpArchivoRes&".doc"
    IF miFso.FileExists(tmpRutaArch) THEN
        response.write "url = """&tmpURLArch&""""&VBNEWLINE         
    END IF
END IF
%>
IF url="" THEN
    MsgBox "SAGRU no encontró el documento solicitado en su almacen interno."&VBNEWLINE&"Contacte al personal de soporte o cree el archivo desde una plantilla.", 0, "Archivo no encontrado"
ELSE

    OA1.CreateNew "Word.Application"        
    document.all.OA1.Open url, <%IF NOT resModificable THEN response.write "true" ELSE response.write "false" END IF%>    
END IF
```

To save the document is as follows:

```
SUB guardarDoc(soloSiEstaSucio, silencioso)
    On Error Resume Next
    dim str : str = ""
    

        <%IF NOT resModificable THEN%>
    str = "Este archivo no debe modificarse!"
    <%ELSE%>
    IF NOT soloSiEstaSucio OR (soloSiEstaSucio AND OA1.IsDirty) THEN
        '### ANTES DE GUARDAR, DEVOLVER LA ETIQUETA Codigo de Impresion ([ci])'
        IF strCodigoImpresion<>"" THEN
            docReemplazarEnTodo document.OA1.Dispatch, strCodigoImpresion, "[ci]"
        END IF
        '### GUARDAR'
         OA1.Save()

    END IF
    IF err.number THEN
        str = "ERROR! - Descripción: "&err.number&err.description&VBNEWLINE&VBNEWLINE
        str = str & "Ocurrió el error descrito mientras se intentaba guardar el documento"&VBNEWLINE&"en el Servidor SAGRU."&VBNEWLINE&VBNEWLINE
        str = str & "Por favor, guarde una copia del archivo e informe del error a la"&VBNEWLINE&"extensión 340 de INE-MGA (incluya los detalles del error)."
    ELSE
    
        str = "Archivo guardado exitosamente."
    END IF
    <%END IF%>
    '### PRESENTAR MENSAJE'
    IF str<>"" AND NOT silencioso THEN
        MsgBox str, 0, "Guardar"
    END IF
END SUB
```

Comment: Where and how is the `guardarDoc` being called? What are the values for the parameters when the sub is invoked?

Comment: SUB OA1_OnFileCommand(itm, cancel)
 'FileNew=0, FileOpen=1, FileClose=2, FileSave=3, FileSaveAs=4, FilePrint=5, FilePageSetup=6, FileProperties=7'
 IF itm=3 OR itm=4 THEN
  guardarDoc false, false
  cancel = true
 ELSEIF itm=5 OR itm=6 OR itm=7 THEN

Comment: Please [edit] and add further info to your question.

Comment: <form action="resoluciones.asp" method="post" name="freso" class="sinMargen" id="freso" onSubmit="if(!confirm('¿Realamente desea guardar estos datos?')) return false; guardarDoc(true, true);">
<br>

Comment: En este caso si le doy refrescar a la pantalla me pregunta si deseo guardar los cambio.

Comment: Check the page source and see what the `guardarDoc` function looks like after the asp part is run. Try putting messageboxes in the code to see where the code is executed or not.

Comment: Could I share the code with you by mail?